# Can I say "speakers were amplifying their laughter"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Is it correct to use *speakers were amplifying their laughter*? For example:

> At the beginning Jack and Jill were just laughing between themselves.
>   But five minutes later they came up to the counter and began to laugh
>   into the cashier's microphone. Now all the speakers in that eatery
>   were amplifying their laughter.

Comment: I looked at the title and thought *Nope.*  ***Speakers were laughing very hard*** *would sound better.* :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the normal relationship between "amplifiers" and "speakers", and the fact that people chatting and laughing may also be referred to as "speakers", I would avoid OP's particular combination.

Perhaps something more like **Now all the loudspeakers in that eatery were broadcasting their laughter** would be better.